# Make calculations on Woocommerce product price html and display it

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In Woocommerce, I have this PHP code that output a product price and its fine.

But I need he too also print the price divided by 10. I tried many ways and it just doesn't work.

Heres the code:

```
    if ($hide_price !== '0') :
        $output_price .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-price dhvc-woo-span6">';
        $output_price .= $product->get_price_html (); //this is where the price is called
        $output_price .= '<p><br>Em até 10x de</p>'; //this is where it should print the price / by 10
        $output_price .= '</div>';
    endif;
    $output .= apply_filters('dhvc_woo_price', $output_price, $product, $display);
```

I tried `$output_price .= $product->get_price_html() / 10;` //it gives me 0

Also tried other ways and it just gave me php error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show your get_price_html() function. That would help to understand the problem.

Comment: It seems that [`get_price_html()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_price_html/) returns HTML, which cannot be divided numerically.

Comment: Avi, heres the price_html from WooCommerce: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html#1702-1719

Comment: Hey Showdev, thank you so much dude. It worked!!

Heres how i did it like the topic you posted:

     $cartao = $product->get_price(); // should return a numeric value, instead of a string
     $totalPrice = $cartao / 10;
     if ($hide_price !== '0') :
      $output_price .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-price dhvc-woo-span6">';
      $output_price .= $product->get_price_html ();
      $output_price .= number_format($totalPrice, 2, ',', '.');
      $output_price .= '</div>';

Damn dude, you saved my day. Thanks everyone who also commented!
Sorry for mybad english, its not my native lang.

Comment: **Not a duplicate**, as it involves also HTML and the provided solution with `get_price()` **is not good** on this linked thread… **The correct way is to use `wc_get_price_to_display($product)`** that will care about **displayed raw price taxes options**…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `wc_get_price_to_display($product)` instead of `$product->get_price_html()` that will output the raw numerical price.

> The **[`wc_get_price_to_display($product)`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_to_display.html#989-1007)** will care about **displayed with tax or not general option**… *(which is not the case for `$product->get_price()`)*.

The code:

```
if ($hide_price !== '0') :
     $output_price .= '<div class="dhvc-woo-price dhvc-woo-span6">';
     $output_price .= $product->get_price_html (); //this is where the price is called

     // Here your correct price divided by 10 and formatted for the output
     $price_d10 = wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product) / 10);
     $output_price .= '<p><br>Em até 10x de '. $price_d10 .'</p>';
     $output_price .= '</div>';
 endif;

 $output .= apply_filters('dhvc_woo_price', $output_price, $product, $display);
```

Tested and works

Comment: For some reason this way it only shows the text. But thanks anyway, you guys here are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$product->get_price()/10;
```

or

```
number_format((float)$product->get_price()/10, 2, '.', '');
```

with 2 decimal places?